# Regular expression for excluding files in a list.file command

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of files named "aaaaXX.txt", where XX are the year's two last digits. To read them, I have written a list.file command:

```
all.files <- as.list(list.files(path="~/datos", pattern = "aaaa"))
```

This solution would be OK if every file share the same columns. However, the files aaaa80.txt to aaaa06.txt are different than the files aaaa07.txt to aaaa22.txt. I tried it, adding a regular expression to the pattern:

```
all.files <- as.list(list.files(path="~/datos", pattern = "aaaa[8-9,0]"))
```

But the list includes those files ending in 07 and higher.

How should I change the pattern specification to include only the files from aaaa80 to aaaa06, and excluding the remaining files from the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "from `aaaa80` to `aaaa06`"? It's not descending ordering because you said that `aaaa07` should not be matched. Please specify **accurate** requirements as to what exactly should be included and what should be excluded. I assume you mean something like 1980 - 2006, since you mentioned years, and exclude years lower/higher than that, but I'm making sure.

Comment: If that assumption is correct, does `aaaa([89]\d|0[0-6])` work for you?

Comment: I omitted the files' full names for simplicity, and replaced it with the acronym 'aaaa'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include an OR condition (with the `|` operator) in the regular expression to limit the file names to those you require.

```
all.files <- as.list(list.files(path="~/datos", pattern = "aaaa([8-9][0-9])|(0[0-6])"))
```

Comment: Great! The OR operator works as expected, and the list includes the files for the years 80 to 06.